# How do I use conditional formatting to notify me of duplicates in across multiple sheets in LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice

I am trying to compile a spreadsheet of all the macros, keyboard shortcuts, and keystroke permutations the applications in my system use.

Obviously, I don't want the macros, shortcuts, and perms to be duplicates of each other, so I want to mark cells in which there are duplicates.

But I don't want them to interfere with the system shortcuts, so that I don't accidentally turn on screenshooter when trying to bevel an edge in Blender.

I have a different sheet for each application, and a separate sheet for system shortcuts, which means that I need to have conditional formatting that works across multiple sheets.

Additionally, I am planning to use multiple keyboards, so I don't want two identical macros, shortcuts, or perms to be marked as duplicates if they are on separate keyboards.  I want this to be in a different conditional format.

How can I have conditional formatting that checks if there is a duplicate in one section, and mark it one way if the data in a different section associated with each member of the duplicates are also duplicates, and a different way if it's not?

Any help would be apprecited!

Comment: two references for you to consider: https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Applying_Conditional_Formatting and https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Faq/Calc/141

Comment: Neither was particularly helpful to this situation.